# VSCode intellisense jsconfig.json exclude jest types for src folder

Tags: visual-studio-code

how to exclude jest globals in intellisense from `src/**/*` ?
I want jest types to be seen only in `test/**.spec.js` files

current configuration:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonJS",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["src/**/*", "typings/index.d.ts"],
  "typeAcquisition": {
    "exclude": [
      "jest"
    ]
  }
}
```

after that i still see jest types in intellisense

[image]